# How to generate vector from set of maps?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have set of maps as below

```
#{{:fname "shaina" :lname "rai"}{:fname "naina" :lname "sen"}}
```

From this set of maps I want to get vector of values attached to key :lname i.e. ["rai" "sen"]

Can any one guide me how can i fetch this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(mapv :lname #{{:fname "shaina" :lname "rai"}{:fname "naina" :lname "sen"}}) 
=> ["sen" "rai"]
```